# setting different layouts for different size in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

```
res/layout/main_activity.xml           
res/layout-small/main_activity.xml   
res/layout-large/main_activity.xml   
res/layout-xlarge/main_activity.xml
res/layout-xlarge-land/main_activity.xml
```

I have two layout files with same name but different text message inside. When i try to load my application in `Samsung-Galaxy 10.1 or Google Nexus 7` Inch tablet or in my emulator where my density is `1024dp * 600dp` it always loads the res/layout/main_activity.xml

I am not sure what mistake i am doing here. Below is manifest file.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sample"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="2.3.4" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />


    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_splash"
             >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Trial"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_trial"
            android:exported="false"
             >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.sample.TRIAL" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

And i am using the android.jar of 4.1.1.4 version.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Statusbar (power, reception etc) take up screen estate. thus if your resolution is 800x600, it's not gonna be 600 but rather 550... so use sw-550dp. though it shouldn't affect width, check that 'sw' thing.

Comment: @Shark: I have updated my folder names differently now. Please do check.

Comment: you have to 'qualify' all layout folders. qualify the default one with the least specs, like layout-h400dp and layout-h1000dp

Comment: @Shark: Can u give me the folder names

Answer (score 0):

According to [this chart](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#testing), 1024x600 is categorized as `xlarge`. You don't have xlarge mentioned in your `<support-screens>` tag.